# While loop with OR not working

Tags: arrays, variables, while-loop

I have this array from which I am trying to assign values to variables, such that one variable is distinct from another and the value is selected at random from the array. I have while loops checking to make sure that the variables do not equal each other.

I have thought about removing elements from the array as they are assigned  to ensure that each element is different but would prefer not to do so if possible.

What I would like is for the while loops to check if 2 variables are equal to continue iterating until it can assign a unique value to that variable, again only using elements from the array. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
int[] bLocation = { 80, 580, 1080 };
        first = (bLocation[new Random().nextInt(bLocation.length)]);
        second = (bLocation[new Random().nextInt(bLocation.length)]);
        while (second==first){
            second = (bLocation[new Random().nextInt(bLocation.length)]);
        }
        third = (bLocation[new Random().nextInt(bLocation.length)]);
        while (third==first||third==second){
            third = (bLocation[new Random().nextInt(bLocation.length)]);
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It's unclear what you want. The title indicates the while loop is not working. Does want an answer on how to fix it or on how to recode it according to last paragraph.

Comment: What I would like to know is why my while loop is not working and if this is the wrong way to approach this situation how would I change what I am doing. The last paragraph was to help clarify what I intend for the loop to do.

Comment: solved it myself. shuffled the array and assigned fixed array elements/position to each variable.                                                                           Random rgen = new Random();  // Random number generator   
   
  for (int i=0; i<bLocation.length; i++) {
      int randomPosition = rgen.nextInt(bLocation.length);
      int temp = bLocation[i];
      bLocation[i] = bLocation[randomPosition];
      bLocation[randomPosition] = temp;
  }
  //Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(bLocation));
  first = (bLocation[0]);
  second = (bLocation[1]);
  third = (bLocation[2]);